# Why Service Worker installed path was "/_/chrome" in google.com?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

Why Service Worker installed path was "/_/chrome" in google.com?

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blG4S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the debugging information in that screenshoot to piece everything together:

- There's a service worker installed with the scope `https://www.google.com/_/chrome`.
- That service worker script is called `newtab-serviceworker.js`.

The actual URL for the service worker script is therefore https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab-serviceworker.js

Reading the code and interpreting the file name, it appears to be a service worker that controls the "new tab page" with user-specific thumbnails and content that Chrome can be configured to display.